# Retry API request until the value is found

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

With the following API I neet to retry the request until the value of response.data.status === "done". Does somebody know how to achieve this?

```
const axios = require("axios");
const qs = require("qs");
let data = qs.stringify({
  document_key: "038A2E0792CE72020E9BB88380D002EB582A6B3AE5883C34DE53C9F17D415D99",
});

let config = {
  method: "post",
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: "https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/document/95BA71197AC66EE4745FF5269CF4399D",
  headers: {
    Authorization: apiKey,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
  data: data,
};

axios
  .request(config)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.status);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
    return;
  });
```

Would like to retry nTimes until the value of response.data.status === "done"

Comment: … if it isn’t done make the request until it is? But I’d probably use an existing retry library that allows a max and uses a back-off algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
const axios = require("axios");
const qs = require("qs");
let data = qs.stringify({
    document_key: "038A2E0792CE72020E9BB88380D002EB582A6B3AE5883C34DE53C9F17D415D99",
});

let config = {
    method: "post",
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: "https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/document/95BA71197AC66EE4745FF5269CF4399D",
    headers: {
        Authorization: apiKey,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    data: data,
};


function retryUntillSuccess(config, callback) {
        axios
        .request(config)
        .then((response) => {
            callback(null, response.data.status);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            retryUntillSuccess(options, callback);
        });
}

retryUntillSuccess(config, function(err, resp) {
    // Your code here...
});
```

I hope the above code works as per ur request. Just a mock function have not tested.